# Call built in type-function manually with arguments

Tags: python

I want to call built in str functions manually (in this case as randomness) without using eval

```py
funcs = [str.lower, str.upper]
random.choice(self.funcs)("test")
```

or

```py
"test".(random.choice(self.funcs))
```

Comment: It looks like you already know how to randomly choose string methods. What more are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
>>> funcs = [str.lower, str.upper]
>>> random.choice(funcs)('Foo')
```

Instead of calling a string's method, like `'Foo'.lower()`, you call the `str` *class's* method, and provide your string as the instance of string that the method is called upon.  Like this:

```
>>> str.lower('FOO')
'foo'
```